# Trouble adding images to C# WPF .NetCore WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

With the intention of exercising I wanted to add an image to the UI of an WPF .NetCore application. In order to do this I use the following code in my XAML.

```xml
<Image Source="images/myimage.png" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="20,20,0,0"/>
```

Normally the code should display my image in the UI while executing the application, but somehow the UI stays empty. For me it was surprising, that the graphical XAML editor of VS shows the image.

I also tried the same with the .Net Framework and here everything worked well. As well I checked the case, that the image is not declared as resource, but this didn't was a solution in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for this problem was to check the project file, ending with `.csproj`. This looked like the following.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

As you can see, the declaration for the image is still missing. So you have to add the following lines to the code above.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Resource Include="images/myimage.png" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Please note that this post is a replication of an older post by me. It's a solution for me, so I don't belive that this is the best practice. I think it's may be helpful for others. That's the reasen why I post it a secound time.

Comment: VS will generate this for you if you add the image file to the project by `Add -> Existing Item...`. You can also write `<ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="images\*" />
  </ItemGroup>` to include all images in that directory.

Comment: @Clemens I know, actually it should. But in my case it doesn't. When I created a folder and dragging the images from file explorer to the project tree, nothing in the project file happens. I mean, you helped me before, so you know my problem, but thank you for the advice! :)

Comment: Try using pack uri to locate the image.

Comment: As said in the other answer, if you set the Build Action to Resource, VS will generate the appropriate entry in the project file.

Comment: @Clemens I know what you mean, but I tried this, moreover on two different machines with the latest version of VS-CE and .NetCore and nothing happen in the project file... I know, it shouldn’t happen, but somehow it didn’t work for me!  I guess dragging the picture directly into the tree from outside VS may is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure when adding the image to the project, the Build Action property for that image file is set to `Resource`.  By default it will be set to `None`.

This is different from .NET Framework projects, where the default for image files already is `Resource`.

Comment: yeah, I tried this... but somehow in vs community edition the project file stays untouched. I don’t know why it didn’t worked, but I did exactly what you say and nothing happen.